# How to Convert int to BSTR?

Tags: c++, bstr

I have a question how can BSTR accepts a number 
the second line here  gives an error

```
    unsigned int number =10;
    BSTR mybstr=SysAllocString(number);
```

also this line gives an error

```
VarBstrCat(mybstr, number, &mybstr);
```

Thank you :) your help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Well, what does the error say? Also, see the documentation for *what* the argument accepted is really used for: [`SysAllocString(number)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221458(v=vs.85).aspx) is most definitely *wrong* and should have raised a warning or two.

Comment: here is the error cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::wstring' to 'const OLECHAR *'

Comment: `SysAllocString` does not have an overload taking an int.

Comment: Thank you MicroVirus so much :) but if I have integer and I need it to be converted to BSTR how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the number to a unicode string before you can get a BSTR of it.
For this you can use `_itow` which converts an `int` into a unicode string.

```
unsigned int number = 10;
wchar_t temp_str[11]; // we assume that the maximal string length can be 10
_itow(number, temp_str, 10);
BSTR mybstr = SysAllocString(temp_str);
```

Answer (score 3):

First, [`SysAllocString` accepts `const OLECHAR*`, not `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221458(v=vs.85).aspx)

Second, [`VarBstrCat`'s second parameter is `BSTR`, not again `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221621(v=vs.85).aspx)

To convert `int` to `BSTR`, you can do for example like this:

```
std::wstring s = std::to_wstring(number); // needs C++11
BSTR mybstr = SysAllocString(s.c_str());
```

UPDATE: Or a bit more efficient, as suggested by [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) in comments:

```
BSTR mybstr = SysAllocStringLen(s.c_str(), s.length());
```

UPDATE2: If your compiler doesn't support C++11, you can use C function `swprintf()`:

```
wchar_t buf[20];
int len = swprintf(buf, 20, L"%d", number);
BSTR mybstr = SysAllocStringLen(buf, len);
```

Comment: Thank you Anton :)
but can u give me a suggestion how to convert int to BSTR ? :)

Comment: Since `wstring` knows its own length, I would suggest using `SysAllocStringLen()` instead: `BSTR mybstr = SysAllocStringLen(s.c_str(), s.length());`

Comment: Thank you Anton but it seems that it is not working with me 

Error 'to_wstring' : is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @RehabReda It's a C++11 function, either enable it by `-std=c++11` or use for example `swprintf`